# ASP.NET GridView "Client-Side Confirmation when Deleting" stopped working on ie - how come?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

A few months ago, I have programmed an ASP.NET GridView with a custom "Delete" LinkButton and Client-Side JavaScript Confirmation according to this msdn article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb428868.aspx (published in April 2007)

or e.g. [Javascript before asp:ButtonField click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218733/javascript-before-aspbuttonfield-click)

The code looks like this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="deleteLinkButton" runat="server" 
    Text="Delete"
    OnCommand="deleteLinkButtonButton_Command"   
    CommandName='<%# Eval("id") %>'
    OnClientClick='<%# Eval("id", "return confirm(\"Delete Id {0}?\")") %>'
  />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Surprisingly, "Cancel" doesn't work no more with my ie (Version: `6.0.2900.2180.xpsp_sp2_qfe.080814-1242`) - it always deletes the row. With Opera (Version 9.62) it still works as expeced and described in the msdn article. More surprisingly, 
on a fellow worker's machine with the same ie version, it still works ("Cancel" will not delete the row).

The generated code looks like

```
<a onclick="return confirm(...);" href="javascript:__doPostBack('...')">
```

As confirm(...) returns false on "Cancel", I expect the __doPostBack event in the href not to be fired. Are there any strange ie settings I accidentally might have changed? What else could be the cause of this weird behaviour? Or is this a "please reinstall WinXP" issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
    CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"
    OnClientClick="return confirm('Delete Id : '<%# (string)Eval('id')%>')" >

</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution at http://forums.asp.net/t/1161858.aspx

In that thread, the root of the problem was ultimately assigned to "The cause was McAfee Phising Filter".

I had to replace the evident line

```
OnClientClick='<%# Eval("id", "return confirm(\"Delete Id {0}?\")") %>'
```

with this cryptic line (I also had to investigate how to escape curly braces), as "event.returnValue=false; makes a difference":

```
OnClientClick='<%# Eval("zahlungid", "if(confirm(\"Delete Id {0}?\")==false){{event.returnValue=false;return false;}}else{{return true;}}") %>'
```