# Make a Buttonfield Execute a javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to execute a JavaScript function on the lcick of a ButtonField of a gridview

As there is no onclick or onclient click present

```
  <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="Submit" Text="Submit" CommandName="Submit"  />
```

Comment: I think you will need to set this in `Row DataBound` event

Comment: @V4Vendetta How to find this ButtonField in RowDataBound?

Comment: Something on these lines `e.Row.Cells[youwouldknowthisindex].Controls[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in grdRewards_RowDataBound we can write

```
  If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
       Dim btnbutton As LinkButton = DirectCast(e.Row.Cells(13).Controls(0), LinkButton)
       btnbutton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return ShowDialog()")
```

Answer (score 5):

Handle the `RowDataBound` event.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
           //Presume that the buttonField is at 1st cell
            LinkButton link = e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as LinkButton;

            if (link != null)
            {
                link.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert('Hello');");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot work with ButtonField for this scenario, better check [Javascript before asp:ButtonField click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218733/javascript-before-aspbuttonfield-click) answered by Steve.

Happy Coding !!

Comment: I have checked that.But I strictly need this buttonfield over here.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowCommandEventArgs e)
{

 if(e.Row.RowIndex != -1)
 {
  //Here Index of Cell will be the No of Delete Column.

  LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[1].Controls[1];
  btn.Attributes.Add("onclick","if (confirm('Are you sure to delete this admin user?')){return true} else {return false}");

}
}
```